# How do I remap names to object properties when deserializing, using Json.Net in C#

Tags: c#, json.net

Case: 
I receive a JSON string from third-party server, containing a list of objects.
e.g.
    [{"foo": "bar", "someotherfield": "somevalue"}, {etc}, {etc}]

I have a C# class like,

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`, but so that it maps "foo" to A and so forth. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `JsonProperty` attribute.

```
[JsonProperty("foo")]
public string A { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `JsonPropertyAttribute` decorated on the property, giving it the name of the parameter it should find in the JSON message. You can also use a custom [JsonConverter](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm), if you do not wish to use an attribute.